# Do you really need "burning", "dvd-burning", "cd-burning" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I have seen that we have several tags on the burning CD/DVD topic. One tag [burn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/burn) has wiki, but there are three more tags on the same topic. These are [burning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/burning), [dvd-burning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dvd-burning) , [cd-burning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cd-burning).

Do we really need those many tags? I think, we can make [burn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/burn) or [burning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/burning) tag master and synonymies other tags.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Yes

We don't need those many tags. Because, the questions under those tags are very similar. And the [burning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/burning) seems more generic. So, it should be the master tag

Comment: I wonder if a more descriptive tag like [tag:disc-burning] would work.

Comment: As long as no questions are asking "Help, my computer is Burning" I think we are ok.

Answer (score 2):

### No

We need those tags.
[cd-burning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cd-burning) is about bruning cd's and very often includes making music cd's
[dvd-buring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dvd-buring) is about burning dvd's and often includes making dvd videos
Tasks that followers of either of the tags would want to keep seperate.

Comment: In relation to hardware the terminology is either burn-in or burning-in so that would be a different tag to just burning.

Comment: cool, done @Cas